# Prove that statistics is sufficient

Tags: statistics

in my wordbook it is said to be true, but I would like to know how to prove it. Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be distributed $Exp(\lambda)$ and $T(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)=X_1+X_2+...+X_n$ Prove that statistics T is sufficient.

The density of $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ is $f_\lambda(X)=\lambda^ne^{-\lambda nx}$ on $x\in<0,\infty)$ the thing is to present this density as a product $f_\lambda(X)=g_\lambda(T(X))h(X)$, but I have no idea how to do it, as $T(X)$ is a sum of coordinates of vector $X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Calculate the mutual density

$$f_\lambda(X_1, \dots, X_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_\lambda (X_i)$$ and the sum you are looking for will apear.

Comment: Omg, i did that but assumed all $X_i$ are tha same... thanks

Comment: Not the same, but the same distribution :)

Comment: If the answer helped, you can accept/upvote so other users know your problem is solved.